# How to find PDE of all planes with the following condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Can someone help with the following problem :

> Find the partial differential equation of all planes which are at a constant distance  $a$ from the origin.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I really have no clue what it means by "partial differential equation of all planes".........................

Comment: I voted to close the question as off-topic. You might want to include more context, such as what kind of PDE you want to obtain (linear or not, how many unknown variables, etc), what form of the equation the solution will take (is it $z = f(x,y)$ or $F(x,y,z)=c$, etc), and what attempts have you made and your thoughts on the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the required equation of the plane be $$z=lx+my+n\\lx+my-z+n=0.....(1)$$Now the plane $(1)$ is at constant distance $a$ from the origin$$\therefore a=\frac{|n|}{\sqrt{l^2+m^2+1}}$$$$\implies a=\frac{\pm n}{\sqrt{l^2+m^2+1}}$$$$\mbox{Here }p=\frac{|ax_1+by_1+cz_1+d|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$$$$\implies n=\frac{\pm n}{\sqrt{l^2+m^2+1}}$$$\therefore (1) $ becomes$$lx+my-z\pm a\sqrt{l^2+m^2+1}=0.....(2)$$Differentiating $(2)$ with respect to $x$ and $y$, we get$$l-\frac{dz}{dx}=0\mbox{ and }m-\frac{dz}{dy}=0$$or$$p=l\mbox{ and }q=m$$$$\therefore(2)\mbox{ reduces to }$$$$px+qy-z\pm a\sqrt{p^2+q^2+1}=0$$$$\implies z=px+qy\pm \sqrt{p^2+q^2+1}\mbox{ is the required differential equation}$$

Comment: What are $p$ and $q$ here?

Comment: @CheeHan $p = \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $q = \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}$